# How to import react component in jsp page Spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jsp, frontend

I am creating Spring boot application and i want my frontend to be with React. The problem comes from the fact that i cannot find a way to properly integrate the react component in my jsp page.

Here is the declaration of the component:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to point out that my jsp page is inside WEB-INF directory and i can successfully redirect to it via a controller, but my import of the component does not work and does not throw an error!

I tried to import it by the element id:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intellij is trash</title>
</head>
<body>
ala bala

<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am i doing something wrong or missed some configuration?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Anyway, your JSP file does not import the JavaScript with the React app.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek i thought if there is a visual representation it would be more helpful. I am new to react how should i import the JavaScript with the React?

Comment: Ehm, ehm, what about reading [the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)? Just instead the `like_button.js` use the file name where your `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));` is.

Answer (score 3):

After importing the React and ReactDOM scripts, import another script where you have written your component App. Assuming it is in App.js,

```
<script src="App.js"></script>
```

Now you need to render the component in the div with id="root". I will use babel to compile but you can do without it too. So after the import write:

```
<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

**Conclusion:** Basically you need to import 4 files in this order: React, ReactDOM, Babel and your component.js files. Then you need to render the component in the div for it to work.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="App.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this way and the react dev tools seem to detect that there is react in the page, but it does not display it. 
in the console i have 2 errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Inline Babel script:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
I tried fixing the first one with the module if i insert the type:
<script type="module" src="../../front-to-the-end/src/App.js"></script> 
but then i get another error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on the jsx in the App.js file

Comment: Just remove the import statements and export default statements from the file to correct the first error. 2nd error can probably be corrected by giving <script type="text/babel">. Try these and report back

Comment: i am new to React how do i export default statements (My app.js has export default App) - Could the problem be coming from the fact that my Spring application is on port 8080 and react is on 3000?
And on the second problem the script has type="text/babel" already - can i just remove it, you said it was not mandatory

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to explain. Can you post a screenshot of your code and errors? That might be helpful

Comment: Did you eventually fix the problem? Are you running your frontend on a separate port and the spring on a separate port?