# Using ReactJS components (JSX) in a JSP project (HTML and JS)

Tags: html, reactjs, jsp, jsx, web-component

What I understand till now is that ReactJS component cannot be used as-is in other applications (JSP).

There is an approach like mentioned in below link, but seems its not recommended for production build:
[How to import react component in jsp page Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976309/how-to-import-react-component-in-jsp-page-spring-boot).

The other approach is to use **Web-components** which is interoperable.

I found that the ReactJS can be converted to Webcomponents by using few libraries like react-to-web-components:
https://github.com/bitovi/react-to-webcomponent

I followed one approach by converting one such **ReactJS component to a Web-component and bundle it to a single .js** bundler by following steps as mentioned in link below:
[Bundle react app created with npx create-react-app to .js file using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604886/bundle-react-app-created-with-npx-create-react-app-to-js-file-using-webpack)

The component still fails to load in my JSP with error:
'CustomElementRegistry': “[object HTMLElement]” is not a valid custom element name

How can I create components in ReactJs and use those in my JSP project? 
I am new to React and Web-component. Could you please help me with some references and examples?

Comment: If you haven't invested in learning technologies yet, disregard React. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304353/main-differences-between-lit-element-react